# What is a convex set $S = \mathbb{R}_{++}^2$

Tags: analysis, hessian-matrix, convexity-inequality

I worked on the following task:

The function $f(x) = f(x_1, x_2) = x_1^{1/2} \cdot x_2^{1/2}$ is concave on the convex set $S = \mathbb{R}_{++}^2$.

I could solve the task with the Hessian matrix (being semi-definitive, i.e. conacave). What I do not really understand is the side note, that the the set is convex. The way I understand it, it has to do, that we only allow for positive inputs for $x_1$ and $x_2$. But what is the connection to convexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** do you know what a [convex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set) is?

**Hint**
Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider $\lambda \in [0,1]$, and:

$$\mathbf{z}(\lambda)=\lambda \mathbf{x} + (1-\lambda) \mathbf{y}$$

is $\mathbf{z}(\lambda) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ true?

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, it means that any any point on the line between x1 and x2 is also part of the set? Of course, that is automatically true if we only allow x1 and x2 to be positive numbers, right?

Comment: Correct, and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you can always get a visual interpretation that is helpful.